# Subgroups between $S_n$ and $S_{n+1}$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Lets look at $S_n$ as subgroup of $S_{n+1}$. 
How many subgroups $H$, $S_{n} \subseteq H \subseteq S_{n+1}$ there are ?

Comment: What can you say about an element of $H$ which is not in $S_n$?

Comment: Stabilizers in primitive (hence 2-transitive) groups are maximal.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

None.

Let $S_n<H<S_{n+1}$ and suppose that $H$ contains a cycle $c$ involving $n+1$, say
$$
c=(a,\cdots,b,n+1).
$$
Then by composing to the left with a suitable permutation $\sigma\in S_n<H$ such that $\sigma(a)=b$ we have
$$
\sigma c=\sigma^\prime (b,n+1)
$$
where $\sigma^\prime(n+1)=(n+1)$, i.e. $\sigma^\prime\in H$. Thus the transposition $(b,n+1)$ is in $H$. Of course we may assume that $b=1$ and so all transpositions $(1,2)$, $(1,3)$, ..., $(1,n+1)$ are in $H$. These transpositions are known to generate $S_{n+1}$.

Comment: Sorry I used a non-standard notation for cycles (the commas aren't usually there) but I couldn't find a way to manage spaces in this TeX environment.

Comment: If by none you mean two... (the inclusions are not necessarily proper on either end!)

Comment: I often put in ~'s for cycle notation. e.g. `$(1~2~3)$`=$(1~2~3)$

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: of course you are right. The "none" incipit was chosen for dramatic effects :) I guess that I should say that I was impliciting assuming that $H$ is not one of the trivial possibilities.

Comment: @anon: thanks for the tip.